# Why does this recursive method work?

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am writing a function to fulfill these requirements: 
Given a string, return true if it is a nesting of zero or more pairs of parenthesis, like `(())` or `((()))`. Suggestion: check the first and last chars, and then recur on what's inside them.

```
nestParen("(())") → true
nestParen("((()))") → true
nestParen("(((x))") → false
```

The correct solution shown on the site is:

```
public boolean nestParen(String str) {
    if (str.equals("")) return true;
    if (str.charAt(0) == '(' && str.charAt(str.length()-1) == ')')
        return nestParen(str.substring(1,str.length()-1));
    else
        return false;
}
```

I don't understand why this works. If the given string has a character other than `(` like a `"`, won't it hit the else case and return false rather than skipping to the next `(`?

Comment: You are correct; `nestParen("((x))")` will return false.

Comment: Yes, it will, as the requirements say it should do.

Comment: None of those strings contain a `"` character though.

Comment: Would this make more sense to you if you changed `if (str.equals("")) return true;` to `if (str.isEmpty()) return true`?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: The outside quotation marks are used to identify that is a string. Any characters within those quotations are the string itself. You would have to use escape characters to have a string containing quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely not work if the input string contain some thing other than `(` and `)`  to make this work just call another function like below before calling this function:

```
clean(String str){
    String str = "(((X+y)+z))";
    String retStr = "";
    for(int i = 0 ; i<str.length() ; i++){
        if(str.charAt(i) == '(' || str.charAt(i) == ')')
        {
            retStr += str.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return retStr
}
```

and then call your recursive function with input of `retStr`.

Answer (score 0):

As seems typical with much example code, the suggested correct solution is inadiquate.

Here is an actually correct solution:

```
public boolean nestParen(final String value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        if (value.isEmpty())
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (value.charAt(0) == '(' && value.charAt(value.length()-1) == ')')
        {
            return nestParen(value.substring(1, value.length()-1));
        }
        else
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
    else // value is null
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Explanation: (same as with the other answer)

1. if the parameter is not null, continue.  This prevents NullPointerExceptions.
2. if the parameter is empty, return true.  The problem appears to be return true if a string contains zero or more nested pairs of parens and nothing else.
3. If the first char is '(' and the last char is ')', strip these chars and check again (this is the recursion).
4. otherwise (first is not '(' and/or last is not ')') return false.
5. lastly, if the parameter was null, return true (it contains zero pairs and nothing else).